# Improving accuracy in scipy.optimize.fsolve with equations involving integration

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, solver, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve an integral equation using the following code (irrelevant parts removed):

```
def _pdf(self, a, b, c, t):
    pdf = some_pdf(a,b,c,t)
    return pdf

def _result(self, a, b, c, flag):
    return fsolve(lambda t: flag - 1 + quad(lambda tau: self._pdf(a, b, c, tau), 0, t)[0], x0)[0]
```

Which takes a probability density function and finds a result `tau` such that the integral of pdf from tau to infinity is equal to `flag`. Note that `x0` is a (float) estimate of the root defined elsewhere in the script. Also note that `flag` is an extremely small number, on the order of `1e-9`.

In my application fsolve only successfully finds a root about 50% of the time. It often just returns `x0`, significantly biasing my results. There is no closed form for the integral of pdf, so I am forced to integrate numerically and feel that this might be introducing some inaccuracy?

EDIT:

This has since been solved using a method other than that described below, but I'd like to get quadpy to work and see if the results improve at all. The specific code I'm trying to get to work is as follows:

```
import quadpy
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import *
from scipy.special import gammaln, kv, gammaincinv, gamma
from scipy.integrate import quad, simps

l = 226.02453163
mu = 0.00212571582056
nu = 4.86569872444
flag = 2.5e-09
estimate = 3 * mu

def pdf(l, mu, nu, t):
    return np.exp(np.log(2) + (l + nu - 1 + 1) / 2 * np.log(l * nu / mu) + (l + nu - 1 - 1) / 2 * np.log(t) + np.log(
        kv(nu - l, 2 * np.sqrt(l * nu / mu * t))) - gammaln(l) - gammaln(nu))


def tail_cdf(l, mu, nu, tau):
    i, error = quadpy.line_segment.adaptive_integrate(
        lambda t: pdf(l, mu, nu, t), [tau, 10000], 1.0e-10
    )
    return i

result = fsolve(lambda tau: flag - tail_cdf(l, mu, nu, tau[0]), estimate)
```

When I run this I get an assertion error from `assert all(lengths > minimum_interval_length)`. I'm not quite sure of how to remedy this; any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If I read your code correctly, the way you've set it up you are wasting 9 digits of accuracy; no wonder scipy is struggling. Can't you perform the integral from _t_ to +infinity?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Sorry, but where do the 9 digits come from?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you ultimately want to match _flag_, a term of order 1e-9. But you do the actual root finding on 1 - _flag_ meaning that if you solve that with a relative accuracy of for example 1e-12 (which is quite demanding and not always possible) and then transform back from 1 - _S_ to _S_ then _S_ will have an absolute error of order 1e-12, so the relative error will be of order 1e-3. If you could instead integrate from _tau_ to +infinity, then you could compare directly to _flag_ and this problem would go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, I tried `1 / x` for the integration between `1` and `alpha` to retrieve the target integral `2.0`. This

```py
import quadpy
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(alpha):
    beta, _ = quadpy.quad(lambda x: 1.0/x, 1, alpha)
    return beta

target = 2.0
res = fsolve(lambda alpha: target - f(alpha), x0=2.0)
print(res)
```

correctly returns `7.38905611`.

The failing quadpy assertion

> `assert all(lengths > minimum_interval_length)`

you're getting means that the adaptive integration hit its limit: Either relax your tolerance a bit, or decrease the `minimum_interval_length` (see [here](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/blob/master/quadpy/line_segment.py#L80)).

Comment: Thanks! I've since gotten this to work with other integration methods, but would like to try and get quadpy to work - I've made an edit to the post above.

Comment: @oirectine Adapted my answer.

Comment: Thanks again - I've tried both relaxing the tolerance and decreasing the minimum_interval_length to no avail. I don't know much about adaptive quadrature; do certain functions potentially not play nice with it? I have also tried to run the `adaptive_integrate` function outside of `fsolve` with known values and have gotten some nonsensical results. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Best file a bug report over at quadpy with an MWE.